# Group by on only some columns?

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have recently inherited some code that looks something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    field1, field2...(600 lines later)... field99
FROM 
    MillionRowTable
WHERE 
    EntryDate > @LastWeek
```

With `distinct`, it takes several hours and locks other people out because it uses 100% of the cpu. Without distinct it's much quicker but it has duplicates.

However I noted that if field1 and field2 are the same as field1 and field2 in another row then I already know they're duplicates and I wouldn't need to check any other column. Is there a way to only group by those 2 columns so I can avoid the duplicates and the 4 hour runtime?

Comment: 1. group by field1, 2 and max(other fileds)
2. row_number() over(partiotion by fileld1, 2) .. where rn = 1

Comment: So you are running `DISTINCT` on 600 columns? My guess is most of the time is spent sorting the records before applying the `DISTINCT` operator. How about inserting without `DISTINCT` to a temp table and sort it out from there?

Comment: Did you try it? If you want to use GROUP By then every column which is not part of a GROUP BY Statement has to be aggregated. In your example it wouldn't work because you cannot Aggregate by field99, right? Or do you want to find duplicate rows?

Comment: I'm actually getting ~100 collumns or so, but there's case statements, math, converts, substrings, etc. Just doing group by on field1 and field2 results in "Field3 is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in the group by clause"

Answer (score 0):

Usual method is to aggregate with `MAX()` or `MIN()`:

```
SELECT field1, field2, MAX(field3) AS field3,...(600 lines later)... MAX(field99) AS field99
FROM MillionRowTable
WHERE EntryDate>@LastWeek
GROUP BY field1, field2
```

Note that not all data types support `MAX()` and `MIN()` (BIT does not, for example) and this may not improve your performance at all.

The second method with `ROW_NUMBER()` works as well, but I'm not sure how well it will work with such a large data set.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT field1, field2...(600 lines later)... field99
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field1, field2 ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
    FROM MillionRowTable
    WHERE EntryDate > @LastWeek
)
SELECT field1, field2...(600 lines later)... field99
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Note that you *must* ORDER BY something with ROW_NUMBER(). `(SELECT 1)` is just something immutable.

If you're locking people out of the database because you're using too much CPU, however, that's an entirely different problem.  You should probably look into fixing that.

Comment: There is actual logic contained within that 600 lines later. Case statements, substrings, math, converts, etc. I should have made that clearer, I apologize. SInce there is that logic in there can I just select * from CTE?

Comment: @lefeal I would not `SELECT *` for production code.  I would list the fields.